# Odoo PoS function on product click

Tags: javascript, odoo, product, point-of-sale

Does anyone has an idea which function is called when a product is clicked in the point of sale?
I'd like to implement some code to automatically include some discount if a product is added to an order.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you just need to extend the ProductListWidget and it's method called click_product_handler().
like following.
but before that just look into that method in base.

```
module.ProductListWidget = module.ProductListWidget.extend({
                init: function(parent, options) {
                this._super(parent,options);
                var self = this;
                this.click_product_handler = function(event){
                << Your Code to add discount >>
                }
}
```